# How do I optimize function in bash script

Tags: bash

Below is the small chunk of my script, In `wau` function I called another function name `whitelableau` having multiple variables like var1, var2 etc.

The problem is that when I ran that script, it execute all variable stored in `whitelableau` and then condition checked when it equals to mentioned string then echo command $var. This outcome takes time to execute.

Script portion:

```
#!/bin/bash

whitelableau() {
     var1=`curl -s 'site' | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d ':' -f2`
    many other variable like above
}

wau() {
whitelableau
    if [ "$opt_var" == "hsandroid" ]; then    ##opt_var argument pass alongwith script
    echo "Active Users: $var1 | Active Users: $var1"
    exit $ST_OK;
elif [ "$opt_var" == "hsbcios" ]; then
    echo "Active Users: $var2 | Active Users: $var2"
    exit $ST_OK;
else
    echo "Parameter not found"
    exit $ST_UK


(( $# )) || echo "No argument supplied, Use -h switch to get help."
while test -n "$1"; do
         case "$1" in
         --help|-h)
            print_help
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
        --activeusers|-a)
            opt_var=$2
            wau
            shift;;
        *)
    echo "Unknown argument: $1"
        print_help
        exit $ST_UK
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

...so on

Debug Output: bash -x script -a hsandroid

```
+ wau
+ whitelableau
++ command execute in $var1
++ cut -d , -f1
++ cut -d : -f2
+ activeusers=145
++ command execute in $var2
++ cut -d , -f1
++ cut -d : -f2
+ activeusersios=202
+ '[' hsandroid == hsandroid ']'
+ echo 'Active Users: 145 | Active Users: 145' Active Users: 145 | Active Users: 145
```

Note: I didn't write some variables here such as $ST_OK.

Comment: The trace shows you are using the external program `cut` rather a lot - but you don't show that code.  Using child processes excessively can seriously slow-up a large program, and there are often built-in alternatives that are faster.  The penalty is often that the built-in methods are harder to read and support.  Without the code I can go no further.

Comment: I am using curl command to get content from specific site and extract information through cut `| cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d ':' -f2`
Which means the actual variable looks `$var1= curl -s 'site' | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d ':' -f2`

Comment: Are you doing that in a loop?  `curl`  could well be your bottleneck.  You need to analyse the performance of every part of your script before coming to conclusions.

Comment: No, I didn't use any loop for curl. Instead use while to pass arguments to script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code that you are actually having trouble with. The function you show is completely trivial and unproblematic.

Comment: I edited the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: The multiple `curl` calls will completely dominate over anything inside these functions. Try to reduce the number of network accesses or perhaps run them in parallel if you need it to run faster.

Comment: Having functions change the variables in other functions is a rather nasty antipattern. You should probably think of a way to make all variables local.

Comment: @tripleee thanks got it. Output takes no time to execute. I have defined it locally.

Comment: Running `nc -z` in a loop 10,000 times is almost 50% slower than running `cut` 10,000 times in a loop. A local network is certainly faster than going out to an external site but it's definitely not "no time to execute". If you have profiling data to suggest that some other part of your code is slower, please do share.

Comment: `var1=${var1%%,*}; var1=${var1#*:}` might get rid of the repeated `cut`s per se, depending on what exactly the input string looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179454/discussion-between-blackninja-and-tripleee).